# Loading Data in UnsubEvent object

Tags: marketing-cloud

I will try my best to phrase the question -

We are using a Custom URL for unsubscribes. So the email going out of SFMC has an Unsubscribe link which points to a Customer preference center.
Now, because of this all the Opt-outs happening on such emails are not getting recorded in SFMC resulting in incomplete tracking.

I want to somehow load these unsubscribes in 'UnsubEvent' object but I don't see any API method supported for this.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted our Salesforce support for this and they gave this magical API **LogUnsubEvent** which can be leveraged when you use Custom Profile Center.

It does exact same thing that out of the box opt-out does

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a Query Activity to identify clicks on the custom unsubscribe links, extract the resulting Data Extension, and import it into All Subscribers.

The query would be something like this:

```
select
c.subscriberkey
, s.emailaddress
, 'unsubscribed' status
from _click c
inner join _subscribers s on (s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid)
where c.linkContent like '%customunsuburl.com/%'
and c.isunique = 1
and s.status != 'unsubscribed'
```

Reference:

- [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)
- [Subscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/)
- [Click](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/)